# Bundle Install passes with no errors, but on visiting the site, I see an Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, bundle, passenger, spree

If I run `bundle install`, the application passes, everything is properly installed.

But if I reboot nginx, and visit the site, I see the Passenger Error message.

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

Error message:
   http://github.com/railsdog/spree.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)

Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::UnknownError

Application root:
    /home/shadyfront/webapps/age_of_revolt/releases/20110214205657
```

I also found out this :

If I do a bundle show spree, It returns :

```
/home/shadyfront/webapps/rails/gems/bundler/gems/spree-594cd0f5a53c
```

but any of the other gems are here at:

```
/home/shadyfront/webapps/rails/gems/gems/ what does that mean?
```

Anyone know why this might be?

**Gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'spree', '0.5.99', :git => 'http://github.com/spree/spree.git' 
gem 'haml'
gem 'ruby-debug'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'ckeditor', '3.4.2.pre'
# aged_revolt gem is a local gem that is generated with Spree extensions
gem "aged_revolt", :require => "aged_revolt", :path => "aged_revolt"
# this is a gem i downloaded and messed with locally
gem "spree_easy_contact", '1.0.2', :path => "#{File.expand_path(__FILE__)}/../vendor/gems/spree_easy_contact-1.0.2"
gem "honeypot-captcha"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what culminated to achieve this, I would simply try this.

`bundle install spree`

Looks like the repo moved to git://github.com/spree/spree.git

Comment: Hmm.. so if I run bundle install, it doesnt' fail. But if I run `bundle install spree`, or if I `gem install spree`, then I get this error for sqlite3 : `Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:`

Comment: Ah ok updated to the new git and the newest version that bypasses the sqlite3 error. But still nonethless leaves me with the same error as above. I updated my answer above. Thanks Hugo!

Comment: I added spree to my project using the same line as you. Two things seem different: I use mysql instad of sqlite and I am reunning the whole thing on webrick. Could you try to change these two parameters and see if anything changes?

Comment: F'in A. I switched to mysql on my local && bundle install. No problem, it works. I go to my server and I do the same thing, and I get a `sqlite3 is trying to be loaded error`. So I remove the entire app and redploy it. This time it says `git://github.com/spree/spree.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)` Ugh..